# Como posso fazer isso de uma forma mais inteligente e sem que haja conflitos?

Tags: java, regex

Desta forma, está retornando alguns erros e parece que pode apresentar conflitos nos casos de operadores de 2 caracteres.

Exemplo: "++" sendo substituído por "#++#" enquanto que na próxima chamada do `replaceAll()` ele vir a substituir os operandos de "#++#" para "##+##+##".

```
private String[] sliptBySpecialCharacteres(String lexeme) {

    return lexeme.replaceAll("==", "#==#")
                 .replaceAll("&&", "#&&#")
                 .replaceAll("=", "#=#")
                 .replaceAll(">", "#>#")
                 .replaceAll("++", "#++#")
                 .replaceAll("<=", "#<=#")
                 .replaceAll("!", "#!#")
                 .replaceAll("-", "#-#")
                 .replaceAll("--", "#--#")
                 .replaceAll("+", "#+#")
                 .replaceAll("+=", "#+=#")
                 .replaceAll("*", "#*#")
                 .replaceAll(",", "#,#")
                 .replaceAll(".", "#.#")
                 .replaceAll("[", "#[#")
                 .replaceAll("{", "#{#")
                 .replaceAll("(", "#(#")
                 .replaceAll(")", "#)#")
                 .replaceAll("}", "#}#")
                 .replaceAll("]", "#]#")
                 .split("#");
}
```

Comment: O objetivo é passar de `++` para `##+##+##` ? E se for `<=` ou `]` ficaria como ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Expressão Regular

Para a parte de substituição, use uma expressão regular para fazer o `replace`. Ao programar a expressão, coloque antes as sequências duplas e depois as simples.

Um bom lugar para testar as expressões regulares é no [RegExr](https://regexr.com).

Exemplo:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String str = "uma * duas = 3 if 45 - 14 == 12 + ( 30 - 12 + [ 15 && 67 ] ) ";
        str = str.replaceAll("(##|[++]|--|[+]|&&|==|>|<|!|-|[+]|=|[*]|,|[.]|\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]|\\(|\\))", "#$1#");

        System.out.println(str);

    }
}

// resultado: uma #*# duas #=# 3 if 45 #-# 14 #==# 12 #+# #(# 30 #-# 12 #+# #[# 15 #&&# 67 #]# #)#
```